# Display selectInput and sliderInput values on action button click

Tags: r, shiny

Created an App in which i wanted to take sliderInput and selectInput from user & display it when we click on action button. Intially when we run the app code works fine but when we change the values in sliderInput & selectInput output is displayed automatically without clicking on button.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title

titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar

  sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("tm", "select the interval", min = 0, max = 20,value = 10),
      selectInput("samples", label = "Select the sample type", c("Sample A","Sample B","Sample C")),
      actionButton("act", label = " Update" )
      ),


    mainPanel(
      textOutput("val"),
      br(),
      textOutput("sam")
    )
  )
))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe(
    if(input$act>0){
  output$val <- renderText(
    paste("You selected the value" ,input$tm)
    )

  output$sam <- renderText(input$samples)

    }
   )
})
```

I want to change the value only when we click action button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `observe`, you can make your output values as `eventReactive`.

Here is the server side codes (as nothing in ui side has to be changed).

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  val = eventReactive(input$act, {
    paste("You selected the value" ,input$tm)
  })

  sam = eventReactive(input$act, {
    input$samples
  })

  output$val = renderText( 
    val()
    )
  output$sam = renderText(
    sam()
  )
})
```